# How to update model using angularjs, Django,Django rest framework

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, angularjs

I have such json representation of a post by its id:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/update/1?format=json
{"title": "about me", "content": "I like program", "created":    "2014-11-29T18:07:18.173Z",   "rating": 1, "id": 1}
```

I try to update rating by button click:

```
 <button ng-click="click(post.id)">Click me</button>
```

I have such javascript code:

```
<script>
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',['ngResource']);
    demoApp.controller( 'AllPosts', function ($scope, $http)
    {
    $http.get('/blogpost/?format=json').success(function(data,status,headers,config)
    {
    $scope.posts = data.results; 
    $scope.predicate = '-title';

      $scope.click = function(post_id, $resource){
       var Post = $resource('/update/:PostId ',{PostId:post_id,format:'json'} );  
       post = Post.get({PostId:post_id}, function() {
       post.rating = post.rating+ 1 ;
       post.$save();
       });
       };

 }).error(function(data,status,headers,config)
     {} )
    ;})

 </script>
```

Peharps i have mistake because in json i have a single object. But i dont really know

Besides i have such view to have a json by certain post by its id:

```
class UpdateModel(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
      lookup_field = 'id'
      queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
      serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer
      permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick tidy up of your `script` tag shows that you are only defining the function `click` if the http call was successful.

I would suggest moving the definition of the click method outside of the success callback.

You may also be running into a race condition that the click function has not been defined before clicking the actual button. Regardless you will want to move that function definition to where the controller is actually created.

Suggested edits (moved `click` definition outside of http call response):

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngResource']);
demoApp.controller('AllPosts', function($scope, $http, $resource) {
    $scope.click = function(post_id) {
        var Post = $resource('/update/:PostId ', {
            PostId: post_id,
            salutation: 'json'
        });
        post = Post.get({
            PostId: post_id
        }, function() {
            post.rating = post.rating + 1;
            post.$save();
        });
    };

    $http.get('/blogpost/?format=json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.posts = data.results;
        $scope.predicate = '-title';
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
})
```

**Updates:**

- Injected $resource into the controller
- Removed $resource from click function params

Comment: I remove click function from success callback but nothing

Comment: I updated my answer to show you what I was talking about rather than just showing your formatted code.

Comment: I've updated again, see updates section in answer. That being said, I'm not familiar with ngResource and I would consider refactoring some of this logic into a service or factory.

Comment: I trying but it dont help

Comment: It would help if you where to copy the output of the browser console. There might be some angular error message there.

Comment: I forgot about csrf protection in django